# Can I use Vault like an Amazon KMS service?

Tags: hashicorp-vault, amazon-kms

I am looking for the system that allows to create and store symmetric master keys in a safe manner. One of such systems is Amazon KMS, where I can create master private key per user and use it to encrypt some data (e.g. user's private keys).

But I need to support several platforms and so I have a question about Vault project (https://www.vaultproject.io). Is it appropriate tool for this task ?

I have found that Vault supports authorization functionality ( https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/userpass.html) and I am wondering is it okay to use this API intensively and store 50k users or so ?

Said that, it looks like these services solve different problems, and Vault is not supposed to be used like Amazon KMS service. But I need to discuss this idea with someone in order to be completely sure.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may look into [Cubbyhole backend](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/cubbyhole/) for Vault. This backend works like a unique space for each token. Destroying the access token deletes all the data stored in its cubbyhole space.

From [Cubbyhole authentication principles](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/cubbyhole-authentication-principles/):

> The `cubbyhole backend` is a simple filesystem abstraction similar to the generic backend (which is mounted by default at secret/) with one important twist:   the entire filesystem is scoped to a single token and is completely inaccessible to any other token.

In other words, it does not matter, what policies attached to the token, but matter what the token is themselves. And only a single token can be used to set or retrieve values in its cubbyhole.